# Forecast package in R ARIMA, what went wrong in this script?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I ran a set of R-commands with the given data (basically extracted from airpassenger data of box jenkins) and I ran into an error which I cannot apprehend.

```
library(forecast)
listr <- c(278.0, 284.0, 277.0, 317.0, 313.0, 318.0, 374.0, 413.0, 405.0, 355.0, 306.0, 271.0, 306.0, 315.0, 301.0, 356.0, 348.0, 355.0, 422.0, 465.0, 467.0, 404.0, 347.0, 305.0, 336.0, 340.0, 318.0, 362.0, 348.0, 363.0, 435.0, 491.0, 505.0)
tseriesr <- ts(listr,start=1,frequency=12)
fitModelr <- arima(tseriesr, order = c(1, 0, 0), seasonal = c(0, 1, 0), method="ML")
```

> Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) :    Lapack routine
>   dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

Comment: If you run the code without the method argument, no error appears, or if you change the method to "CSS" it works too. So the error must be in the "ML"-argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think like this, it will run:

```
fitModelr <- arima(tseriesr, order = c(1L, 0L, 0L), seasonal = c(0, 1, 0), method="ML", transform.pars = FALSE)
fitModelr <- arima(tseriesr, order = c(1L, 0L, 0L), seasonal = c(0, 1, 0), method="CSS-ML")
```

See this [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html) page.